# H2o parameter search with sklearn RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, h2o

I'm trying to fine best parameters for h2o model using sklearn `RandomizedSearchCV`. Code (taken from this [documentation](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turchin/2/docs-website/h2o-docs/booklets/Python_booklet.pdf)):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
iris_df = h2o.import_file(path="iris.data")

params = {
          "gbm__ntrees":            [10,20],
          "gbm__max_depth":         [1,2,3],
          "gbm__learn_rate":        [0.1,0.2]
         }

pipeline = Pipeline([("gbm", H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(distribution="gaussian"))])

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, params,
                                   n_iter=5,
                                   scoring="roc_auc",
                                   random_state=42,
                                   n_jobs=1)

random_search.fit(iris_df[1:], iris_df[0])
```

But it gives me the following error:

`ValueError: Unexpected __getitem__ selector: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

I tried different datasets and also tried to pass `pandas.DataFrame` instead of `h2o.frame`, and it gives the following:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cbind'`

What is happening? `h2o` now is not compatible with `sklearn`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are following older documentation. H2O has its own random grid search method. See below.

```
#GBM hyperparameters
gbm_params = {'ntrees': [10, 20], 'max_depth': [1, 2, 3], 'learn_rate': [0.1, 0.2]}

# Search criteria
search_criteria = {'strategy': 'RandomDiscrete', 'max_models': 5, 'seed': 42}

# Train and validate a random grid of GBMs
gbm_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(distribution="gaussian"), grid_id='gbm_grid', hyper_params=gbm_params, search_criteria=search_criteria)
gbm_grid.train(x=predictor_columns, y=response_column, training_frame=iris_df)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html#random-grid-search-examples) for more info.